# Случайно запретил alert на сайте. Как снова разрешить? Firefox

Tags: firefox

Случайно нажал на галочку запретить alert на сайте, когда появилось это окошко. Как снова разрешить? firefox. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Гугл выдает неадекватные результаты -- вообще на противоположную тему

Comment: [Site Permissions panel](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/site-permissions-panel)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо. Но к сожалению, там нет запроса на alert. На аудио\видео есть. А на всплывающие окна или другой синоним - нет. Только один пункт отображается(

Comment: Попробуйте перезагрузить браузер.